# Selenium chromedriver 2.27.440174 don't run the Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a `Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m` and `selenium.version 3.0.1`.

`Chrome.exe` based in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application`

pom file

```
    <selenium.version>3.0.1</selenium.version>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-remote-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I run the code

```
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    searchBox.sendKeys("ChromeDriver");
    searchBox.submit();
    Thread.sleep(5000);  // Let the user actually see something!
    driver.quit();
```

And have a error

```
    Starting ChromeDriver 2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9) on port 18032
Only local connections are allowed.
янв 10, 2017 12:18:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Attempting bi-dialect session, assuming Postel's Law holds true on the remote end
Starting ChromeDriver 2.25.426923 (0390b88869384d6eb0d5d09729679f934aab9eed) on port 9515
Only local connections are allowed.
[0.003][SEVERE]: bind() returned an error: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted. (0x2740)
янв 10, 2017 12:19:56 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchSessionException: no such session
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 20 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.0.1', revision: '1969d75', time: '2016-10-18 09:49:13 -0700'
System info: host: 'EPRUMOSL15047', ip: '192.255.10.140', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.8.0_65'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{message=chrome not reachable
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.27.440174 (e97a722caafc2d3a8b807ee115bfb307f7d2cfd9),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64), platform=ANY}]
Session ID: 3506210c8a0eb0d3b9abfdb238547455
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:635)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:322)
    at utils.Main.main(Main.java:19)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I also tried the versions and got error

1. Google Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m 64 bit
2. Google Chrome 54
3. Google Chrome 53 x64 and x86
4. Google Chrome 51 x64 and x86

Tell me what could be the reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get `NoSuchSessionException` when the Chrome executable cannot be found; in fact `{message=chrome not reachable` seems to indicate just that.

I have the Chrome exe in the same location as you (`C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` version `55.0.2883.87 m`, ChromeDriver `v2.25`, Selenium `3.0.1`, on Windows 8.1) and in my case the exe is found without having to specify its path (it's the "default location", see [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver)) so I would expect it was found also in your case, but my tests don't use a pom file or Maven.

You might try to set the Chrome path explicitly, as you can see [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/capabilities) under *Using a Chrome executable in a non-standard location*, if anything to rule out the executable location as the cause. That would be:

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.setBinary("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe");
ChromeDriver browser = new ChromeDriver(options);
```